PHP PhpSpreadsheet, Chart: Not able to use multiple bar types in a single chart
When creating Excel file with a chart inside I am not able to place multiple bar plot types in a single chart. This code works:
private function _exportSampleTestingChart1()
   {
      $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
      $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
      $worksheet->fromArray(
         [
            ['', 'Rainfall (mm)', 'Temperature (°F)', 'Humidity (%)'],
            ['Jan', 78, 52, 61],
            ['Feb', 64, 54, 62],
            ['Mar', 62, 57, 63],
            ['Apr', 21, 62, 59],
            ['May', 11, 75, 60],
            ['Jun', 1, 75, 57],
            ['Jul', 1, 79, 56],
            ['Aug', 1, 79, 59],
            ['Sep', 10, 75, 60],
            ['Oct', 40, 68, 63],
            ['Nov', 69, 62, 64],
            ['Dec', 89, 57, 66],
         ]
      );

      // Set the Labels for each data series we want to plot
      //     Datatype
      //     Cell reference for data
      //     Format Code
      //     Number of datapoints in series
      //     Data values
      //     Data Marker
      $dataSeriesLabels1 = [
         new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$B$1', null, 1), // Temperature
      ];
      $dataSeriesLabels2 = [
         new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$C$1', null, 1), // Rainfall
      ];
      $dataSeriesLabels3 = [
         new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$D$1', null, 1), // Humidity
      ];

      // Set the X-Axis Labels
      //     Datatype
      //     Cell reference for data
      //     Format Code
      //     Number of datapoints in series
      //     Data values
      //     Data Marker
      $xAxisTickValues = [
         new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$13', null, 12), // Jan to Dec
      ];

      // Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
      //     Datatype
      //     Cell reference for data
      //     Format Code
      //     Number of datapoints in series
      //     Data values
      //     Data Marker
      $dataSeriesValues1 = [
         new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$B$2:$B$13', null, 12),
      ];

      // Build the dataseries
      $series1 = new DataSeries(
         DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART, // plotType
         DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED, // plotGrouping
         range(0, count($dataSeriesValues1) - 1), // plotOrder
         $dataSeriesLabels1, // plotLabel
         $xAxisTickValues, // plotCategory
         $dataSeriesValues1        // plotValues
      );
      // Set additional dataseries parameters
      //     Make it a vertical column rather than a horizontal bar graph
      $series1->setPlotDirection(DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);

      // Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
      //     Datatype
      //     Cell reference for data
      //     Format Code
      //     Number of datapoints in series
      //     Data values
      //     Data Marker
      $dataSeriesValues2 = [
         new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$C$2:$C$13', null, 12),
      ];

      // Build the dataseries
      $series2 = new DataSeries(
         DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART, // plotType
         DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD, // plotGrouping
         range(0, count($dataSeriesValues2) - 1), // plotOrder
         $dataSeriesLabels2, // plotLabel
         [], // plotCategory
         $dataSeriesValues2        // plotValues
      );

      // Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
      //     Datatype
      //     Cell reference for data
      //     Format Code
      //     Number of datapoints in series
      //     Data values
      //     Data Marker
      $dataSeriesValues3 = [
         new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$D$2:$D$13', null, 12),
      ];

      // Build the dataseries
      $series3 = new DataSeries(
         DataSeries::TYPE_AREACHART, // plotType
         DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD, // plotGrouping
         range(0, count($dataSeriesValues2) - 1), // plotOrder
         $dataSeriesLabels3, // plotLabel
         [], // plotCategory
         $dataSeriesValues3        // plotValues
      );

      // Set the series in the plot area
      $plotArea = new PlotArea(null, [$series1, $series2, $series3]);
      // Set the chart legend
      $legend = new ChartLegend(ChartLegend::POSITION_RIGHT, null, false);

      $title = new Title('Average Weather Chart for Crete');

      // Create the chart
      $chart = new ExcelChart(
         'chart1', // name
         $title, // title
         $legend, // legend
         $plotArea, // plotArea
         true, // plotVisibleOnly
         DataSeries::EMPTY_AS_GAP, // displayBlanksAs
         null, // xAxisLabel
         null   // yAxisLabel
      );

      // Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
      $chart->setTopLeftPosition('F2');
      $chart->setBottomRightPosition('O16');

      // Add the chart to the worksheet
      $worksheet->addChart($chart);
      $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
      $writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
      $writer->save('php://output');
   }

But if I try to use 'DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART' also in the second series, $series2, like this:
$series2 = new DataSeries(
  // DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART, // plotType
  // DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD, // plotGrouping
  DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART, // plotType - like in $series1
  DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED, // plotGrouping - like in $series1
  range(0, count($dataSeriesValues2) - 1), // plotOrder
  $dataSeriesLabels2, // plotLabel
   $xAxisTickValues, // plotCategory
  $dataSeriesValues2        // plotValues
);

Then it fails. Chart is blank. Basically it is not possible to combine two or more bar types (DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART) in a single chart.
What must be changed in the code?
